# Multiply entire column by a random number and store it as new column

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a column with 100 rows and i want to generate multiple columns(say 100) from this column. These new columns should be generated by multiplying the first column with a random value. Is there a way to do it using python? I have tried it using excel but that is a tedious task as for every column I have to multiply the column with a randomly generated number (randbetween(a,b)).

Comment: your question is unclear, can you add some sample input of what you are using initially and sample output of what you would like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have a column of numeric data:

```py
import numpy as np
import random

# random.randint(a,b) will choose a random integer between a and b
# this will create a column that is 96 elements long
col = [random.randint(0,500) for i in range(96)]
```

Now, let's create more columns by leveraging a `numpy.array` which supports scalar multiplication of vectors:

```py
arr = np.array(col)

# our dataframe has one column in it
df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=['x'])
a, b = 100, 5000 # set what interval to select random numbers from
```

Now, you can loop through to add in new columns

```py
num_cols = 99

for i in range(num_cols): # or however many columns you want to add
    df[i] = df.x * random.randint(a,b)

df.head()
     x        0        1       2        3        4        5        6  ...      92      93      94       95       96       97      98       99
0   68   257040   214268  107576   266152   229568   309468   319668  ...   74460   25024   85952   320620   331840   175712   87788   254864
1  286  1081080   901186  452452  1119404   965536  1301586  1344486  ...  313170  105248  361504  1348490  1395680   739024  369226  1071928
2  421  1591380  1326571  666022  1647794  1421296  1915971  1979121  ...  460995  154928  532144  1985015  2054480  1087864  543511  1577908
3   13    49140    40963   20566    50882    43888    59163    61113  ...   14235    4784   16432    61295    63440    33592   16783    48724
4  344  1300320  1083944  544208  1346416  1161344  1565544  1617144  ...  376680  126592  434816  1621960  1678720   888896  444104  1289312

[5 rows x 101 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response @C.Nivs. This solution gives me an array which serves as the first column. How can I modify it such that it takes the existing column and then multiply it with the random number and store the result into multiple columns

Comment: @Param an existing column like `df['x']`? Also, I'm not quite sure what you mean by *multiply [the existing column] with the random number and store the result into multiple columns*. Multiplying a column by a random integer will give you a new `pd.Series` which can be stored as a column

Comment: I have a dataset (96x1). I want to generate 100 columns based on this 1 column. It has to be done by multiplying the values of this  column by a random value such that the final dataset is 96x100. I hope this clears your question.

Comment: I think this should already answer it. You are taking your existing column `df.x`, multiplying it by a random value between `a` and `b`, and storing that as a new column. You can adjust the `range(100)` to be however many columns you need to add

Comment: As a note, I used `df.head` to reduce the amount of output, which is why it says only 5 rows, but there are 96 in reality

Comment: df.x is a column generated from random selection of numbers between 0 and 500. But I want to use the column I have in my dataset. My dataset has a column 'day1' and i want to use to create additional columns. I dont want the column x created here in the dataframe df.

Comment: Ok, then replace `df.x` with `df.day1`. I didn't see `day1` in your question, so I made an analogous dataset

Answer (score 1):

You can use Numpy reshape to multiply column with random number

```
a, b = 10 ,20
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':np.random.randint(0,500, 100)})
df['col'].values * np.random.randint(a, b, 100).reshape(-1,1)
```

To get the result in a Dataframe,

```
pd.DataFrame(df['col'].values * np.random.randint(a, b, 100).reshape(-1,1))
```